# List of categories doesn't appear when creating a new parcel in Postmaster

Tags: add-on, categories, postmaster

When creating a new parcel in Postmaster (1.2 beta, build 1.1.99.4), I always find that after selecting a channel, the list of categories for that channel never updates. The text remains as, "This channel has no categories." Even though there are categories for the channel that I selected.

The statuses do update, so I wonder if I'm missing something from the setup as to why these categories don't appear right away? After saving the parcel and going back into it, the categories do then appear.

Comment: Do you have MSM installed? The categories are dynamically pulled based on the category group that assigned to that channel. In theory, if the category group is assigned to a specific channel, it will appear in that list. If you can confirm you have this setup correctly, I will take a look as it is likely a new bug as a result of trying to fix MSM compatibility issues.

Comment: No, I'm not using the MSM on this site. Given that the categories do appear after the parcel has been saved and I return to edit the parcel, maybe it's a bug then? Unless there's any setup I've missed somewhere?

Comment: This is likely a bug then. I will do some tests on my end today and post back to this thread.

Comment: Okay thanks Justin. If it's a bug then it's certainly only a minor one. Will be good to know I'm not doing something wrong elsewhere though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to follow up with this thread, this bug has been fixed in my latest development build and will be available in the v1.2 release.

Email support[at]objectivehtml.com if you need access to the beta build.